# Unknown application in notifications

Tags: notifications

I have unknown notification in my Notifications. I have all the necessary notifications like, Network, Power, terminal, Music, Geary, thunderbird etc.,

How can I remove it from Notifications menu.

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to remove it by using `dconf`

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor #to install dconf-editor
```

Open `dconf-editor` --> org --> pantheon --> gala --> notifications.

Here you will see: **apps** the corresponding value should have entries like: `'appname:show,on'`. But you will see an entry without `appname` like just `':show,on'`.

(The actual syntax is :`['{APP-NAME}:{PRIORITY (show/hide)},{SOUNDS on/off}', ...]`)

*Remove it, it will remove the unknow notification icon*.

[image: Imgur]

After removing `':show,on'`:

[image: Imgur]

You can make the notifications to default by clicking <kbd>Set to Default</kbd> in `dconf` (See screenshot above).

---

**Using terminal**:

Open terminal and run:

```
gsettings get org.pantheon.desktop.gala.notifications apps
```

It  gives the **similar** output:

`['NetworkManager:show,on', 'Power:show,on', 'terminal:show,on', 'guake!:show,on', 'org.pantheon.noise:show,on', 'vlc:show,on', 'vlc media player:show,on', 'xneur:show,on', ':show,on', 'thunderbird:show,on', 'geary:show,on']`

You will see *`':show,on'`* in the output.

Now run:

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.notifications apps "[]"
```

Inside the [], copy paste the above output except `':show,on'`

For example:

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.notifications apps "['NetworkManager:show,on', 'Power:show,on', 'terminal:show,on', 'guake\!:show,on', 'org.pantheon.noise:show,on', 'vlc:show,on', 'vlc media player:show,on', 'xneur:show,on', 'thunderbird:show,on', 'geary:show,on']"
```

*Note*: I have used `\` before `!` as escape sequence in the example.